# How to remove hamburger menu button when the menu bar is disabled in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Before the update, I liked to disable `show menu bar`.
The menu disappeared and you just have to press `Alt` key to show it again.
[image]

But now `Alt` key doesn't work because there is a new hamburger menu button on the Activity Bar.

[image]
Is it possible to remove the hamburger menu icon?

Comment: Just right-click that icon or anywhere in the Activity Bar and disable `Menu`.

Comment: Mark is correct. Right-click on the Activity-Bar, you should see a list of tools/extensions. The extensions that show a check mark are selected. The selected extension show their Icon inside of the Activity-Bar. To remove an Icon, deselect it by clicking on it in the right-click menu. You should no longer see a check-mark by it, and the icon displayed within the activity-bar should also be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Open `File`
Choose `Preferences`
Choose `Settings`
Search for `window.menuBarVisibility`

Set this according to your preference.  `toggle` removes the new hamburger icon and only shows when you hit `Alt`.